# Gridlines for multiple plots when displayed by Show

Tags: graphics

#### Question

Suppose that I am using `Show` to display several plots — for example, two plots and three contourplots.

Is there a nice way to add gridlines?

#### Elaboration

I realize I can just stick the gridlines into the first of the plot expressions, but sometimes when I'm changing functions around that gets confusing.

I thought `Epilog` would be a nice way to do this, but I don't think `Gridlines` works on the righthand side of an `Epilog` option.?

Perhaps the best option would  be something like making a function that does exactly what I want. That is, a function that takes the plots I want to display and the gridlines I want as inputs and then combines them.

If it's the latter, then I don't need to see a solution — that is, it would be both above my current level and more than I need for now.

I am just curious if there is a simple, built-in way (other than putting gridlines into the first of the plot expressions)

---

Sorry for no minimal working example; I feel like the question can be understood/addressed without one.

Comment: why not `Show[plot1,plot2, ..., plotn, GridLines->{{x1,x2,..., xk},{y1,y2,...,ym}}]` (where the lists `{x1,x2,..., xk}` and `{y1,y2,...,ym}` specify the positions of horizontal and vertical gridlines, respectively)?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment. I had an "Epilog" in my show and I guess I was putting gridlines in the epilog. Whoops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `GridLines`, or any other `Graphics` options, directly to [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html):

```
Show[
  plot1,
  plot2, 
  GridLines -> ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you can simply say GridLines->Automatic in the options in Show
2. I always have grid lines in my plots, I feel any plot is incomplete without those wonderfully thin gridlines. So I have

SetOptions[#, GridLines -> Automatic] & /@ {Plot, ListPlot, ListLinePlot, PolarPlot, AudioPlot, BoxWhiskerChart, DistributionChart,DateListPlot,Histogram,ParametricPlot, ComplexListPlot,BarChart,DateHistogram,StreamPlot,VectorPlot};

in my init.m anyway, and then you don't have the problem in the first place.